# How to move bugfixes across branches in DVCS?

Tags: git, mercurial, branch, dvcs, bazaar

If we discover bug in some branche we fix it (check *New* release on picture). But also we interesting in moving this fix to *Old* release and *Main* development branch:

```
a-->b-->c              (Old release)
|    
A-->B-->C-->D           (Main release)
    |
    1-->2-->bugfix-->4  (New release)
```

**svn** remember in svn:merge properties (from svn 1.6, 2009) which revision merged to which branches. So next time if you merge region of revisions previously merged revisions was skipped from merge patch.

How deal with modern DVCS?

I need make plain patch and apply it to each branches or there are exist some help from DVCS?

**Note**: I can not just merge *New* branche to *Main* as previous changesets move also to *Main* branche.

Rebase also not possible as *New* release come to many developers.

I interesting in answer for named braches schema and for multirepository schema.

**PS.** *Andy* suggest find common parent to all branches for which bug have affect, update to it, apply fix to the bug and move fix to affected branches.

By updating to old changeset and making changes you create new branch. I recommend create named branch (name it as **bugID**), so later you can easy back to it.

There are problem on finding common parent to all branches in which we have interest to fix bug.

First solution (that suggest *Andy*) is using **$ hg/git/bzr blame** and carefully check output for all affected files. This involve first fix bug on *some newest* changeset before you find with **blame** what changeset introduce a bug. Then you need **rebase** fix (patch) to common parent changeset.

Another solution is using **$ hg/git/bzr bisect** (you can also manually perform updates to find first revision in which bug introduced). This can be expansive but more *true* solution as allow populate bugfix to **any** branches in which bug present.

I think it is better first find *first BAD* changeset and then fix a bug, instead of first fix a bug and then find *first BAD* changeset (except case when you already know how fix bug). Also having a diff that introduce can help in understanding why it occur.

**PPS.** With bugs it is clear which branch effected to allow merge changes to any effected branch.

Interesting question come if ask how backport feature from development branch to release branch. As you can see you must commit feature changesets starting with changeset that before release branch. But when you develop feature you can don't know where you need backport feature. With **svn:merge** VCS remember for you all backports. How about DVCS?

Comment: cherry-pick could cause confusion within your history if they are ever merged back together.

Comment: @Andy: what kind of difficulties?

Comment: Sorry, I meant confusion (just edited it as  you wrote your response).  When merged back together, you're now going to have duplicate commits.

Comment: But you won't have any conflicts, so it shouldn't bring any problems, right?

Comment: Yeah, it will merge back in fine, but if for some reason you merged the two branches back into master, you will now have three identical commits in your your repo and history.  Wasted overhead, and confusion as you see the same bug is fixed multiple times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could:

1. Find common parent. *Thanks to Novelocrat for this step.*
   `git merge-base branch1 branch2 branch3 ...`
2. Checkout the common parent
   `git checkout A`
3. create new branch to fix bugs on
   `git checkout -b bugFix`
4. Make bug fixes and commit them to bugFix branch
5. Checkout branch that needs the bug fix
   `git checkout branchToApplyFixTo`
6. Merge the bugFix into the branch
   `git merge bugFix`

Comment: Nice. Only the problem that I see is a calculating of common parent to **all** branches for which bugfix is relevant.

Comment: You could use date from `git blame` to see when the bug was created and decide your branch point from there.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I update question with your suggestion. I also recommend use **bisect** to find common **BAD** parent.

Comment: Git has a built in command `merge-base` to find the common ancestor of a list of commits/branches.

Answer (score 3):

You could `git cherry-pick bugfix` on each affected branch that you want to fix. This would generate a new commit id for the fix on each branch, though.

Answer (score 2):

This why people make separate branches for each feature or bug fix.  Then the only trick is to make sure when you create the branch, it is from a point that excludes any commits you wouldn't want included in every branch you intend to merge back into.  If you forget, you can just rebase it to that point before doing any merges.  If you don't catch it until after it's merged back into your new release branch as shown in your example, the best option is probably cherry picking, although that can make future merges very difficult if you use it too often.

Comment: Git's merge is supposed to handle cherry-picks, I think, but I can easily see how it would create sticky situations if one is not careful.