# merge-base analog for Mercurial and bzr (to find common ancestors as possible for a merge)?

Tags: git, mercurial, merge, bazaar

Git have **merge-base** command that show common ancestors of two or more branches.

What analog for Mercurial and bzr?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [revsets](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets):

```
"ancestor(single, single)"
      Greatest common ancestor of the two changesets.

$ hg log -r 'ancestor(rev1, rev2)'
```

Comment: **ancestors(set)** is perfect!

Answer (score 9):

For Bazaar:

```
bzr find-merge-base /path/to/branch1 /path/to/branch2
```

(This command is hidden from the main set of commands that you can obtain with `bzr help commands`. Use `bzr help hidden-commands` to see other hidden commands).

Comment: It seems like this *should* work, however for me it always returns the current revid (when passing either revids or revnos).

Answer (score 6):

For Mercurial:

`hg debugancestor rev1 rev2`

Comment: Thanks for answer. This command hidden from **hg help** but can be viewed if type **hg debug**. Unhappily this command allow only TWO changesets, git-merge-base allow any number of changesets.

Comment: @gavenkoa I believe Mercurial doesn't allow merging more than two branches in a single commit (a git octopus merge).  Mercurial developers probably didn't see the need to have a command to find the common ancestor for a merge you aren't allowed to do.

Comment: But this functioanality is useful. To find in which revision start bugfix/feature-development to avoid *cherry-picking* in case if you have 3 or more banches to propagate changes with **hg merge**. Look my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709365/how-to-move-bugfixes-across-branches-in-dvcs